# Google-charts: Transparency not working?

Tags: transparency, google-visualization

I'm trying to make a google-chart with transparency, but it seems not to work. It just draws a solid white background.

Does anybody succeded with transparency?
Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Info about google charts: [solid fill](http://code.google.com/intl/ca/apis/chart/colors.html#solid_fill)

Test URL:
[Google-charts example](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?20%2C25=&chco=ff0000%2C00ff00&chd=t%3A4%2C4%2C4%2C4%2C4%2C4%2C4|10%2C0%2C30%2C0%2C10%2C0%2C0&chdl=puntuaci%C3%B3%20m%C3%A0xima|puntuaci%C3%B3%20obtinguda&chdlp=t&chf=a%2Cs%2CEFEFEFFF&chm=o%2C00ff00%2C1%2C0%2C7|o%2C00ff00%2C1%2C1%2C7|o%2C00ff00%2C1%2C2%2C7|o%2C00ff00%2C1%2C3%2C7|o%2C00ff00%2C1%2C4%2C7|o%2C00ff00%2C1%2C5%2C7|o%2C00ff00%2C1%2C6%2C7&chs=692x432&cht=lc&chxl=0%3A|A|B|C|D|E|F|G&chxr=1%2C0%2C4%2C1&chxt=x%2Cy)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a transparent background, use
    chf=bg,s,FFFFFF00

Example:
[image]

Comment: Right! I thought the transparency like an alpha channel: the higher the value the more transparency you get.
Obviously, it works like css-opacity. Thanks Ville!